order of the reaction with respect to acid ions
The acid catalysed hydrolysis of an organic compound $( \text{A} )$ at $( 303  \text{K} $) has a time for half change of $( 100\  \text{minutes} )$ when carried out in a buffer solution at $( \text{pH} = 5 $), and $( 10 \ \text{minutes} $) when carried out at $( \text{pH} = 4 $). Both times of half change are independent of the initial concentration of $( \text{A} $). If the rate of reaction is given by
$$
-\frac{d[\text{A}]}{dt} = k_0[\text{A}]^x[\text{H}^+]^y,
$$
find the values of ( x ) and ( y ).
First, I proceeded with the question thinking that since, the half life is independent of the concentration of $[\text{A}]$ the order should be $1$ with respect to A. And when the concentration increased by a factor of 10, changing the pH from 5 to 4, the half time reduced by a factor of 10. And since, the half time is inversely proportional to the concentration of $[\text{H}^+]$, it's order should be 2. But the answer given is that the order of $[\text{H}^+]$ is 1 as well. I don't understand how it's derived. Is my way to predict the order with respect to change in a particular species wrong? And if yes, what's wrong. And what's the correct way to determine the order of a species given how it affects the half time of the main reactant for which the half time is defined.
Does the solution being a buffer has to do something with this?

Provide the reasoning why  it should be 2.

I considered how the half time of the reaction changed with concentration of H+. And when the concentration increased by a factor of 10, changing the pH from 5 to 4, the half time reduced by a factor of 10. Hence, the half time is inversely proportional to the concentration of H+. Comparing it to the integrated rate equation of a second order reaction, I thought the order of H+ should be 2.

The rate is proportional to [H+]

I'm sorry but I don't understand. How can you tell? Only the half life is given, corresponding to the initial concentration. How did you determine that the rate is proportional. It might change later, only the initial conditions are provided. That too for the half life only.

As it is a catalyst, $\dfrac{\text{d}[\ce{H+}]}{\text{d}t} = 0$
The order with respect to [$\ce{A}]$ has been already detemined to be 1.
Let's assume for now that the catalysis rate is of the order 1 with respect to $[\ce{H+}]$, i.e. proportional to $[\ce{H+}]$
$$k=k_0 [\ce{H+}]=\dfrac{\ln{2}}{T_{0.5}}$$
$$T_{0.5} \cdot k_0 [\ce{H+}]=\ln{2}$$
$$0.1 \times T_{0.5} \times  k_0 \times  10 \cdot [\ce{H+}]=\ln{2}$$
In such a case,

increasing [H+] ten times
and predicted decreasing the half-time ten times
matches the observed decreasing the half-time ten times.


Thanks, I got it. Just one more question, the overall order of this reaction would be 1, or to be precise, pseudo first order, right?

Rather 2, pseudo 1.  H+ is not even in excess about constant. It Is constant.

If the half-time is independent of the initial concentration of A, it means that the reaction is first-order with respect to A.
If the half time is inversely proportional to the concentration of $\ce{H+}$, it means that the reaction  is first-order with respect to $\ce{H+}$.
So the parameters $x$ and $y$ are both equal to $1$.
If you don't understand, please read books about kinetics like Kinetics and Mechanism, by A. A. Frost and R. G. Pearson, John Wiley and Sons, 1981, p. 41 - 44.

But isn't half time in first order reaction independent of the initial concentration of the reactant? So, why can you say differently about [H+]?

@AnantTyagi Notice that it is catalysis, so [H+] is constant.
